# lcr game c++ LINK 2019 error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a school project due Sunday.  It is an LCR Dice game in C++ using Visual Studio 2017.  I cannot get past 2 link2019 errors. I have included code of all instances where these functions are defined and called.  I tried to change the way that I call them and tried to remove the static Player::directions but no luck.  Because it is a linker error, Visual Studio does not find it until compile time.  I have tried to search for answers, but I cannot find anything specific to my problem. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you. 
 Here are the exact errors:

```
    "LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall 
    Player::setName(void)" (?setName@Player@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function 
    _main   LCR Game    C:\Users\docmo\Desktop\SNHU files\IT 312 C++ 
    Programming\LCR Game\LCR Game\LCR Game.obj  1"
```

and

```
    "LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl 
    Player::directions(void)" (?directions@Player@@SAXXZ) referenced in 
    function _main  LCR Game    C:\Users\docmo\Desktop\SNHU files\IT 312 C++ 
    Programming\LCR Game\LCR Game\LCR Game.obj  1"
```

Here is the C++ code:

```
Player.h:
    #pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Dice.h"

class Player
{

public:
int chips;
int numPlayers;
std::string name = "";

Player() = default;

void setName();
void setChips();
int checkChips();
static void directions();
};

Player.cpp:
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Dice.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;

void Player::setName()
{
    std::cin >> name;
}
...<more code>
void Player::directions() //display directions to player
...<more code>

LCR Game.cpp
// LCR Game.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include "Dice.h"
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;
...<more code>
for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) //loop to set names and chips for each 
player
{
    cout << "Enter player name: " << endl;

    players[i].setName();
    players[i].chips = 3;
}
Player::directions(); //display game rules to player



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is Player.cpp actually in your project?

Comment: BTW, you don't need `#include "stdafx.h"` nor precompiled headers unless you have a huge project.  I recommend not using precompiled headers as they add unnecessary complexity to small projects.

Comment: Yes, Player.cpp is in the project.  There are two other functions in there called void Player::setChips() and and int Player::checkChips() and they are not throwing the error.  Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: `using namespace System::IO;` This looks like managed `c++` to me. I believe it should be tagged with `c++-cli` instead of `c++`

Comment: ***There are two other functions in there called void Player::setChips() and and int Player::checkChips() and they are not throwing the error.*** Are these 2 other functions used in your code? Perhaps you need to do a clean build.

Comment: Yes they are and they are not throwing any errors to the linker.  I just went to build/clean solution.  Then I rebuilt it and the same thing.  This is driving me nuts.  If I comment out the call to these functions in the LCR Game.cpp, the errors go away. I even created a new project and pasted my code into it, but I get the same errors.

Comment: Are the functions that are working also in the `player.cpp` file.

Comment: Yes, the other functions are in the player.cpp and they do not throw those errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  It is a beginners foolish mistake.  Even though I added the files in Microsoft Studio to my project, it did not include them.  I had to select each file in the Server Explorer and then select Project then include in project.  Thanks for all the help.